# pointer type for buffer which contains multiple different types

Tags: c++, pointers, buffer

If I want to declare a pointer to a buffer, and the buffer contains multiple different types (int, char, etc.), then what type am I supposed to make the pointer to the buffer? void *?

Comment: How are the data stored? binary? have you ever heard about [TLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value)?

Comment: I don't think we have enough info to answer. How do you determine the contents' type when you use the buffer, for example? Anyway, at first glance, it seems like re-thinking the design might be in order.

Comment: I am adding contents to the buffer using a program called Game Maker Studio. I am using a GML (Game Maker Language) function called [buffer_write](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/buffers/buffer_write.html)  to store data. I am getting the address to the buffer using [buffer_get_address](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/buffers/buffer_get_address.html) and passing the address into a DLL so that I can access the buffer from the DLL.

Comment: GM Studio only uses two types: "string" and "real". I believe that those translate into char and double, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `void *` is the generic pointer. But you should use it with precaution. If you want to use a library then the [any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/any.html) type of [boost](http://boost.org) library is a safe generic container

Answer (score 1):

From your description it appears like you are trying to design your own serialization of different types into a buffer (in real life doing this in a portable way is difficult and for most cases a well defined serialization library like [protocol buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) solves the problem).

In past in cases where I had used custom buffer management I have seen three ways people managing their buffers

1. void* and carefully manage the offsets in your code
2. char* and use the fact that char* would be a byte.
3. uint8_t* as a portable way to read a byte of data from the buffer.

Remember that if you are allocating a buffer to manage different types of data, you will end up reading bytes carefully and casting it to appropriate types. I like the 3rd approach as a clean way to read bytes from the buffer and maintain the byte alignment in the buffer in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Under windows, you can use VARIANT.
Under Linux, you can copy the relate

```
struct tagVARIANT
    {
    union 
        {
        struct __tagVARIANT
            {
            VARTYPE vt;
            WORD wReserved1;
            WORD wReserved2;
            WORD wReserved3;
            union 
                {
                LONGLONG llVal;
                LONG lVal;
                BYTE bVal;
                SHORT iVal;
                FLOAT fltVal;
                DOUBLE dblVal;
                VARIANT_BOOL boolVal;
                _VARIANT_BOOL bool;
                SCODE scode;
                CY cyVal;
                DATE date;
                BSTR bstrVal;
                IUnknown *punkVal;
                IDispatch *pdispVal;
                SAFEARRAY *parray;
                BYTE *pbVal;
                SHORT *piVal;
                LONG *plVal;
                LONGLONG *pllVal;
                FLOAT *pfltVal;
                DOUBLE *pdblVal;
                VARIANT_BOOL *pboolVal;
                _VARIANT_BOOL *pbool;
                SCODE *pscode;
                CY *pcyVal;
                DATE *pdate;
                BSTR *pbstrVal;
                IUnknown **ppunkVal;
                IDispatch **ppdispVal;
                SAFEARRAY **pparray;
                VARIANT *pvarVal;
                PVOID byref;
                CHAR cVal;
                USHORT uiVal;
                ULONG ulVal;
                ULONGLONG ullVal;
                INT intVal;
                UINT uintVal;
                DECIMAL *pdecVal;
                CHAR *pcVal;
                USHORT *puiVal;
                ULONG *pulVal;
                ULONGLONG *pullVal;
                INT *pintVal;
                UINT *puintVal;
                struct __tagBRECORD
                    {
                    PVOID pvRecord;
                    IRecordInfo *pRecInfo;
                    }   __VARIANT_NAME_4;
                }   __VARIANT_NAME_3;
            }   __VARIANT_NAME_2;
        DECIMAL decVal;
        }   __VARIANT_NAME_1;
    } ;
```

Use it as a variable like as the variable in script language.

Comment: I have no clue how this helps in any way.

Answer (score -1):

If you want one pointer to a collection of different types, you should use a struct:

```
struct T {
  char C;
  int I;
  ...
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
T* ptr = &T();
ptr->C = "d";
ptr->I = 1337;
```

Comment: That last section won't compile.